# Weird Behavior on cloning object in visualforce

Tags: visualforce-component, clone, angularjs

I'm having some weird issue where I'm trying to make a deep copy of an object on a button click, but when I do it rotates between a successful clone, and a copy of the object without any of the nested objects. Here's my code

Here's the angular section where it's happening

```
<button ng-click="populateModalSearch()"><span>Copy Main Page Filters</span></button>
...
<ui-select theme="select2" focus-on='SetFocusModal' multiple="multiple" ng-model="modalSearch.sites">
    <ui-select-match  placeholder="select site" allow-clear="true">
        <span ng-bind="$item.Name"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="site in allSites">
        <div ng-bind-html="site.Name | highlight: $select.search"> 
        </div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

```
$scope.populateModalSearch = function() {
    console.log('search', $scope.search);
    $scope.modalSearch = _.cloneDeep($scope.search);
    // Also tried
    // $scope.modalSearch = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.search));
    // This works though, only for shallow copy
    // $scope.modalSearch = {...$scope.search};
    console.log('modalsearch', $scope.modalSearch);
}
```

The weird thing is that on the object summary it shows that the object has contents, but when I expand the console log it's empty

Here are some of the logging outputs I'm getting when I click
First Click:
[image]

Second Click:
[image]

Comment: Do you get similar weirdness if you stringify then JSON parse to generate the clone?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I'm not sure we can help you. From my point of view, I feel like this question is off-topic, because, unless you can prove it is Visualforce-specific, what you really have is just a plain old Angular problem. Would you please [edit] in more code so we can get full context?

Comment: @PhilW Yeah the same thing happens when I stringify and parse the code.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm not sure what other code you'll need - I added the html portion of the angular code as well.

Comment: I'm confused... the "first click" and "second click" console dumps of the objects both appear to have worked. What hasn't worked here? Please [edit] the question to add more detail. Can you also provide examples of what you get when using the old-fashioned JSON stringify/parse approach?

Comment: The first click dump shows that the 'sites' parameter in the modalSearch is empty, after some debugging I think it's caused in the ui-element where with the ng-model that updates the modalSearch object? I'm not sure